# When a function returns true or false does it actually returns a string of true or false?

Tags: php

I have a basic simple question. Consider the following code

```
function checkNumber($number)
{
    if (is_numeric($number))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

$isValidNumber = checkNumber(123);
```

Will isValidNumber variable contain a string of value true?

Comment: bool value...:- https://3v4l.org/0v6cb (it's simple to check via `var_dump()`) . but you have to use it carefully as php interpreted it as 0,1

Comment: Add just... `return is_numeric($number);`

Comment: _“Will isValidNumber variable contain a string of value true?”_ - no. Of course it won’t. Why should it? You are not returning string values, but booleans – so who what where how should feel inclined to change their type to something else?

Answer (score 1):

It will return a bool value. Can you check it by `var_dump($isValidNumber)`.

Result is:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will always be a boolean because even if you just return `is_numeric($number)` it will be a bool because the function itself returns a boolean like explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Even if you made useless stuff like

```
function checkNumber($number)
{
   return $is_numeric($number);
}

$isValidNumber = checkNumber(123);
```

`$number` will be always an boolean in your case.